# jQuery ajax with multiple nested .when inside. Returns undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

jQuery ajax with multiple nested .when is not returning properly.  Getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u" because of undefined variable.

Below is my code and the flow.

This method will be called on the event of a button click which internally calls multiple methods with dependencies.  In the below example the flow is masterProcess->buildAndroidApk->unlockAndroidKey

```
function masterProcess(thisForm){
  $.when(buildAndroidApk()).then(function(result){
    obj = JSON.parse(result);

  });
}

function buildAndroidApk(){
  $.when(unlockAndroidKey()).then(function(result){
    obj = JSON.parse(result);

    //There are some other .when based on the obj response

    return result;
  });
}

function unlockAndroidKey(){
  //this function connects to server via jQuery Ajax and gets a json string inside success or error block
  return '{"success":"1","message":"","content":null}';
}
```

The function unlockAndroidKey gets the json string and I could able to receive that inside buildAndroidApk.  But the masterProcess is receiving an undefined string and JSON.parse results in error "Unexpected token u".

I am not sure whether I have explained my query clearly but if required I can explain in more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not showing any async operations, thus we can't even help you with the actual async code.  That's what we would need to see in order to help you.

All sorts of issues:

1. `$.when()` must be passed one or more promises
2. `$.when()` is not needed at all if you only have one promise to wait on as you can just use `.then()` directly on the single promise.
3. `buildAndroidApk()` and `unlockAndroidKey()` must return promises
4. The test JSON string you were trying to return has syntax errors in it (bad quoting)
5. If you're using jQuery and you are getting JSON back from your server, jQuery will parse it for you automatically - there's no need for you to parse it manually.

For your code to work the way you have it structured, both `buildAndroidApk()` and `unlockAndroidKey()` MUST return promises.  Right now, you aren't showing a return of a promise in either function.  Thus, when you try to use `.then()` on the return value, it won't work.  Or, when you try to pass it to `$.when()`, there's no promise to wait on.

`$.when()` requires one or more promises to be passed to it.  Your `buildAndroidApk()` method does NOT return a promise so thus you are passing undefined to `$.when()` so it has no promise to wait on before calling its `.then()` handler.

In addition, there is no reason to use `$.when()` unless you have more than one promise.

---

You aren't showing us the actual async portion of your code so it's a little hard to show you how to actually fix the code, but here's the general idea:

```
function masterProcess(thisForm){
  buildAndroidApk().then(function(result){
    obj = JSON.parse(result);
    // use obj here
  });
}

function buildAndroidApk(){
  return unlockAndroidKey().then(function(result){
    obj = JSON.parse(result);

    //There are some other .when based on the obj response

    return result;
  });
}

function unlockAndroidKey(){
  //this function connects to server via jQuery Ajax and gets a json string inside success or error block
  return $.ajax(...).then(function(data) {
       return something;
  });
}
```

Comment: Just for understanding purposes I hardcoded the json string in my code.  Actually I build the json using array in php and does JSON::parse in javascript.  You are correct, the function buildAndroidApk() is not returning the promise.  After I put the return before $.when now it is getting returned.

Comment: @Malaiselvan - do you understand that you don't need `$.when()` when you only have one promise.  You can just use `.then()` directly on the promise.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.  I put a return before $.when and it works fine.

```
function buildAndroidApk(){
  return $.when(unlockAndroidKey()).then(function(result){
    obj = JSON.parse(result);

    //There are some other .when based on the obj response

    return result;
  });
}
```